# Bootstrap popover: change the content of a popover on a dynamic created element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have this popover script I use on static element that is working great:

```
$(".popover-class").popover({
        title: fetchTitle,
        content: 'loading...', 
        html: true,
        placement: 'right'
    }).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
        var popover = $(this).attr('data-content', fetchData).data('bs.popover');
        popover.setContent();
        popover.$tip.addClass(popover.options.placement);
});
```

Where "fetchData" is a function that call an ajax request on a script that retrieve some data from the myssql.

In another page I want to do the same thing, but on dynamically generated elements. I understode I have to call the popover from the "body", but then the ".attr('data-content'" is no more working and I don't understand why.

Here is the non-working script:

```
$("body").popover({
        title: fetchTitle,
        content: 'loading...',
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        placement: 'right',
        trigger: "hover",
        selector: '.popover_ajax'
    }).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
        console.log('test'); // <- this is working 
        var popover = $(this).attr('data-content', 'new text').data('bs.popover');
        popover.setContent();
        popover.update();
        // <-- all this is not working, the popover remain with text "loading.."

    });
```

The popover is generating but it stays with text "loading..", it won't change.
Am I missing something? With 'body' maybe somethings should be called differently?

Comment: You're attempting to get the attribute from the body element. Is that where it exists?

Comment: whaa! Thank you very much, this was the error!
If I write this way is now working correctly!
`var popover = $('.popover_ajax').attr('data-content', 'new text').data('bs.popover'); `

Comment: The only problem is that now with $('.popover_ajax') he loads the content of all the popover, not only the one I'm over with the mouse. Is there a solution also for that?

Comment: `$('.popover_ajax')` will match all elements on the page, you want to just match the one that was clicked. Maybe the [`.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) would work: `....on('shown.bs.popover', function (event) { var popover = $(event.target).attr('data-content)...` ?

Comment: wow, that's what I was searching for, thank you!

Comment: Which Bootstrap version do you use here? I guess 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the attribute from the body element by using `this`.

```
$("body").popover({
    title: fetchTitle,
    content: 'loading...',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    placement: 'right',
    trigger: "hover",
    selector: '.popover_ajax'
}).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    var popover = $(event.target).attr('data-content', 'new text').data('bs.popover');
    popover.setContent();
    popover.update();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.popover_ajax')` will match all elements on the page, you want to just match the one that was clicked.  The event handler will receive the event as a parameter, and you can find the event target from that:

```
.on('shown.bs.popover', function (event) { 
    var popover = $(event.target).attr('data-content', 'new text')...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, which works in my scenario:

```
$("body").popover({
    title: fetchTitle,
    content: 'loading...',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    placement: 'right',
    trigger: "hover",
    selector: '.popover_ajax'
}).on('show.bs.popover', async (e)=>{
   const popover = bootstrap.Popover.getInstance(e.target);
   let newContent = await fetchData();
   popover._config.content = newContent;
});
```

`popover._config.content` is key here.